# Add custom button dynamically to Fullcalendar in Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I am trying to add/hide custom buttons based on screen size. Here is my code for calendar configuration

```
windowResize: function(){
$('.fc-scroller').css('height', 'auto');
        var ww = $(window).width();

        if (!$('#billBtn').length) {
            $('.fc-toolbar').find('.fc-clear').before('<div id="billBtn" class="" style="margin-top:0.5em;"><button id="billBtn1" class="fc-left fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right fc-state-hover">Prev Bill: 0</button></div>')
            $('.fc-toolbar').find('.fc-clear').before('<div id="newOrderBtn" class="fc-right"><button id="newOrderBtn1" type="button" class="fc-NewOrder2-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right fc-state-hover" onclick="clickNewOrder()">New Order</button></span>')
        }
        if (ww < 600) {
            $('.fc-Bill-button').hide();
            $('.fc-NewOrder-button').hide();
            $('#billBtn').css("display", "block");
            $('#newOrderBtn').css("display", "block");
        }
        else {
            $('#billBtn').hide();
            $('#newOrderBtn').hide();
            $('.fc-Bill-button').css("display", "block");
            $('.fc-NewOrder-button').css("display", "block");
        }
},
customButtons: {
                NewOrder: {
                    text: 'New Order',
                    click: vm.clickNewOrder
                },
                Bill: {
                    text: 'Prev Bill: 0.0',
                }
            },
```

Click event for 'New Order' button is working fine on desktop view.
For mobile view, I am hiding both these custom buttons ("New Order" and "Bill") and creating new buttons since I want these two buttons in another row. I am able to display the buttons but the click event is not working. I am unable to figure out how to solve this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why are you adding the buttons dynamically on resizing? Add them immediately after you declare the calendar, but leave them hidden. You're less likely to have issues with event handling them. BTW do you get any console errors when you try and click your new buttons?

Comment: Yes, I am getting following error

'Uncaught ReferenceError: clickNewOrder is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick'

How to add buttons immediately after declaring the calendar?

Comment: presumably you have a `$("#calendar").fullCalendar...` bit of code, of which your sample above is just one part? So just immediately on the next line after that statement is finished, you could move the two lines starting with `$('.fc-toolbar').find('.fc-clear').before('<div id="billBtn" ...` etc to there instead. So it would only run once.

Comment: As to the error message, I notice you call it "clickNewOrder" in the "new" buttons, but "vm.ClickNewOrder" in the "customButtons" declaration. Should they not be the same? What is "vm"?

Comment: I got "Uncaught ReferenceError: vm is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick" with vm.ClickNewOrder

Comment: I am using angularjs, not sure how to proceed further, I am stuck here...

Comment: well I don't know what "vm" is or how/where it's defined, so I can't help you with that very easily. Only you know where your ClickNewOrder function is placed in the code. You have obviously got a scope error of some kind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144547/discussion-between-srikanth-b-and-adyson).

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything at all about angular. I looked at the question because it appeared be about fullCalendar, but really it's just about variable/function scope. You probably want to reframe the question showing the wider context of the code and where the functions you want are declared relative to each other.

Comment: okay, anyway thanks for your time.